Getting "could not determine executable to run" when using npx create-react-app
I'm following a React course.
I already created a React app using create react app then I needed to install react routes and some vulnerabilities showed nd, I ran npm audit fix --force now the npm run start doesn't work and npx create react app doesn't work (tried it on a new project). I reinstalled node and nothing changed.
The error shows :*npm error could not determine executable to run
npm error 

A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\amar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-22T09_44_09_91* 


----------


Complete log :

*0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.8.2
2 info using node@v20.17.0
3 silly config load:file:C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config load:file:C:\Users\amar\Documents\GitHub\essai\.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:C:\Users\amar\.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm exec create react app amar
8 verbose argv "exec" "--" "create" "react" "app" "amar"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\amar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-22T09_40_20_370Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\amar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-22T09_40_20_370Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
12 silly logfile done cleaning log files
13 silly packumentCache heap:2197815296 maxSize:549453824 maxEntrySize:274726912
14 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create 2809ms (cache revalidated)
15 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
15 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
15 verbose stack     at exec (C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:202:15)
15 verbose stack     at async Npm.exec (C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:207:9)
15 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\amar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli\entry.js:74:5)
16 verbose pkgid create@0.0.2
17 error could not determine executable to run
18 verbose cwd C:\Users\amar\Documents\GitHub\essai
19 verbose os Windows_NT 10.0.22621
20 verbose node v20.17.0
21 verbose npm  v10.8.2
22 verbose exit 1
23 verbose code 1
24 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\amar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-22T09_40_20_370Z-debug-0.log*


create-react-app died last year. Try vite

Not sure why you're experiencing that issue but why not use vite instead? Even the React team recommend against initialising a new project with create-react-app.

It might work with older node versions. There is a good chance you will run into a problem at some point when using it and then you are stuck cos it isn't maintained anymore. It is annoying to have to switch to Vite but it is what we decided to do so we weren't building or learning with already obsolete tech

Vite will take some learning. https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html  The good news is that is has pretty good documentation in my experience. It will take some time to red and absorb before you can use it as a replacement for create-react-app based training (if at all - it may be too confusing)
